# Detecting Collisions between Colliders in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

How can I identify a collision between two different BoxCollider2D objects in Unity in the OnCollisionEnter,Exit, and Stay Methods using Collision2D in C#. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When I have multiple colliders that should trigger different actions I **place them in different game object children**.

For example, if I have one character (game object) with two different colliders, one for the head and another one for the rest of the body, that trigger different actions I create two game object inside the character. Then **each child will have its script** containing `OnCollision` methods.

You can also name each game object (head and body) or change their tag and then you can identify the colliders using `this.gameObject.name` or `this.gameObject.tag` since this will be running in different game objects.

I think this makes game logic simple instead of handling multiple actions inside the same game object collision functions and it has been working good for me so far.